# Show not only the reprint data but also non-printed one? Using left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-join

```
select
    barcode,
    fullname,
    social,
    printdate,
    (case
        when min(orderId) = 0 then 'yes'
        when min(orderid) <> 0 then 'No'
    end) as Reprint
from
    clientdata (nolock)
left outer join ReprintTable with(nolock) on
    Code = barcode
where
    clientcode = '334556'
    --and printdate < '2021-02-23'

    group by barcode,
    fullname,
    social,
    printdate
order by
    printdate
```

Logic behind this query:

So basically I want to show all the reprinted card but also the non-reprinted one, I'm using left outer join to join reprint table (which stores all the information for reprint cards, like reprint date)

Basically if the orderid of card is 0, then that means the cards has been reprinted, vice versa.

I want to get my query to show all the non-reprinted cards and exclude the reprinted cards that was reprinted before 23rd, but once I added that `and` clause in, the non-reprinted cards are no longer showing.

How do I fix this.

The output if I add the `and` clause back in (not real data, but using example):

```
barcode     fullname        Social   PrintDate          Reprint
024556      Donald Wick     4556     2021-01-03         yes
024557      John Trump      4558     2021-01-08         yes
```

If I take out the `and` clause:

```
barcode     fullname        Social   PrintDate          Reprint
024556      Donald Wick     4556     2021-01-03         yes
024557      John Trump      4558     2021-01-08         yes
024557      Stop Gambling   4556     null               no
```

etc...

Anyway I can get the non-reprinted data showing along with my filtered reprint range?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Does `printdate` belong to the `ReprintTable` table by chance? FYI... I hope you are aware of the consequences of using `nolock` all over the place - its not recommended.

Comment: Yes printdate belongs to the reprint table

Comment: Hey it worked. Thanks! that was a typo

Comment: Aside: If `orderId` isn't nullable then your `case` expression can be simplified to: `case when min( orderId ) = 0 then 'yes' else 'No' end as Reprint`. It's either zero or not (if you have ruled out `is NULL`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the case when `printdate` is null - which is will be when no record exists in the `ReprintTable` table.

If you alias your tables and prefix your columns with the table alias things become a lot clearer.

Note also that it may not order as you expect since some `PrintDate` values are null.

```
select barcode, fullname, Social, RT.PrintDate
    , (
        case when min(orderId) = 0 then 'yes'
        when min(orderid) <> 0 then 'No'    
        end
    ) as Reprint 
from ClientData CD with (nolock)
left outer join ReprintTable RT with (nolock) on Code = barcode
where clientcode = '334556'
and (RT.PrintDate is null or RT.PrintDate < '2021-02-23')
group by barcode, fullname, Social, RT.printdate
order by RT.PrintDate
```